# Incompatibilidade de tipos e dificuldade em ler um vetor

Tags: pascal

Estou com dificuldade em um problema, que a principio pensei ser bem trivial, mas no final não consegui fazê-lo. Trata-se de um exercício de uma prova de Algoritmos ele está abaixo:

JOGO MASTERMIND

CONSIDERE AS SEGUINTES DEFINIÇÕES:

```
const MAX = 20;          CORINI = 1;          CORFIM = 30;

type cores: CORINI..CORFIM;       (*faixa de valores, subtipo de integer*)

vetor = array [1..MAX] of cores;
```

---

1.Escreva,em Pascal, procedimentos ou funções para:

(a)Ler um vetor com n ∈[2..MAX] elementos do tipo cores, garantindo que todos os elementos pertencem ao intervalo[CORINI,CORFIM] e que não haja nenhum elemento repetido no vetor lido;

Fiz o programa na linguagem pascal, porém estou com o seguinte erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei como, aceitar um valor qualquer do usuário, integer digamos, e atribui-lo em uma variável do type cores.
O meu código está abaixo:

```
program mastermind;
const MAX = 20;      CORINI = 1;      CORFIM = 30;

type cores = CORINI..CORFIM; (*faixa de valores, subtipo de integer*)
     vetor = array [1..MAX] of cores;

var vetor_de_cores: vetor; n: integer;


function esta_no_intervalo(n: integer): Boolean;
begin
    esta_no_intervalo:= False;
    if (n >= 1) and (n <= 30) then
        esta_no_intervalo:= True;
end; 

function eh_repetido(vetor_de_cores: vetor; limitador: integer; x: integer): Boolean;
var i: integer;
begin
    eh_repetido:= True;
    if limitador = 1 then
        eh_repetido:= False
    else 
    begin
        for i:= 1 to limitador-1 do
        begin
            if vetor_de_cores[i] = x then
                eh_repetido:= False;
        end;
    end;

end;

function valor_valido(var x: cores; vetor_de_cores: vetor; i: integer): cores;
begin
    while (esta_no_intervalo(x) = False) or (eh_repetido(vetor_de_cores, i, x) = True) do
    begin
        writeln('Entrada invalida');
        read(x);
        valor_valido:= x;
    end;
end;

procedure ler_vetor(var n: integer; var vetor_de_cores: vetor);
var i: integer; x: integer;
begin
    for i:= 1 to n do 
    begin
        read(x);
        vetor_de_cores := valor_valido(x, vetor_de_cores, i);

    end;
end;


(*PROGRAMA PRINCIPAL*)
begin
    read(n); (*n é um tam do vetor entre 2 e MAX*)
    ler_vetor(n, vetor_de_cores);

end.
```

Comment: Na linha 50 você está chamando a função ```valor_valido``` passando o primeiro argumento o "x" que foi declarado como inteiro. Ele está esperando uma variável do tipo "cores". ```vetor_de_cores := valor_valido(x, vetor_de_cores, i);``` . Sugestão: Altere o tipo do primeiro argumento da função ```valor_valido``` , assim: ```function valor_valido(var x: integer; vetor_de_cores: vetor; i: integer): cores;```

Comment: Fiz as modificações, porém continua o problema, porque a função 'valor_valido' recebe o 'x', porém esse x é do tipo integer.

Comment: Percebi também que se eu modificar todas as ocorrências de x, para o tipo 'cores', se o usuário digitar um valor acima de 255 ou menor que 0 o resultado é um número pseudoaleatório, mas que em alguns momentos está na faixa do intervalo do tipo 'cores'.